# Extract headings, subheadings and paragraphs from PDF files using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to extract the headings, subheadings and paragraphs from PDF files

For example, my text is:

```
  1. Abstract 

    Some text 1



   2. Introduction 

    some text 2

   2.1. Background

       some text 2.1

  2.2. Reviews

       some text 2.2

  3. Methods

    some text 3


  4. References

    references
```

The `headings` list will be:

> 1. Abstract, 2. Introduction, 2.1. Background, 2.2. Reviews, 3. Methods, 4. References)

and the `paragraphs` list will be:

> some text 1, some text 2, some text 2.1, some text 2.2, some text 3, references

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Tika package:

```
import tika
from tika import parser

parsedPDF = parser.from_file("./File/Path.pdf")
print(parsedPDF['content'])
print(parsedPDF['metadata'])
```